# Класс объектов-действий

Tags: delphi, объекты

Привет. Вопрос такой: видел несколько раз в объекте присвоение ссылки на функцию, вот интересно стало. Допустим, мне надо сделать класс TMyAction, в котором есть несколько параметров и ссылка на процедуру. Как сие организовать?

```
[...]
type TMyAction = class(TObject)
  Param1: string;
  Param2: string;
  Param3: string;
  procedure Action; (* тут явно что-то должно быть *)

var MyAction1, MyAction2: TMyAction;

procedure someFunc;
procedure someFunc2;
[...]
begin
[...]
MyAction1.Action := @someFunc;
MyAction2.Action := @someFunc2;
end.
```

Вот как-то так) Что это возможно, я знаю, наблюдал. Вопрос - где в этом куске чего дописать?

**UPD** идеально вот такое использование

```
if (act = 'go') then
  with MyAction1 do begin
    Param1 := var1;
    Param2 := var2;
    Action := goProcedure;
    end;
```

- доступ к параметрам из процедур.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коментах места не хватило ))

Тут вариантов куча
Для такой реализации с какой мы начали можно поступить так

```
procedure someFunc (Sender:TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(TMyAction(Sender).Param1);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyAction1: TMyAction;
begin
  MyAction1 :=TMyAction.Create;
  MyAction1.Param1:='dsadasdas';

  MyAction1.Action := someFunc;

  MyAction1.Action(MyAction1);
end;
```

но я бы реализавал так

```
  TmyProcedure = procedure (Param1,Param2,Param3: string);

  TMyAction = class(TObject)
    Param1: string;
    Param2: string;
    Param3: string;
    Action: TmyProcedure
  end;
```

...

```
procedure someFunc (Param1,Param2,Param3: string);
begin
  ShowMessage(Param1);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyAction1: TMyAction;
begin
  MyAction1 :=TMyAction.Create;
  MyAction1.Param1:='dsadasdas';

  MyAction1.Action := someFunc;

  MyAction1.Action(MyAction1.Param1,MyAction1.Param3,MyAction1.Param3);
end;
```

Но это можно сказать личное дело каждого.

Comment: >>MyAction1.Action := someFunc;
>>MyAction1.Action(MyAction1.Param1,MyAction1.Param3,MyAction1.Param3);

о_О

Нужно делать:
в TmyAction
реализовать метод:
public:
...
procedure call();
begin
if assigned(Action) then
   Action(Param1,Param2,Param3);
end;

ну и вызывать соответсвенно call, а не action которому еще и параметры нужно передавать

Comment: О, я вспомнил конструкцию `with Sender as TMyAction do` =) Вот, отлично, спасибо) Второй вариант не совсем айс, потому как планируется в одном событии устанавливать что-то типа `Act := NextAction`, а совсем в другом (и возможно в другом потоке) `if Act.Ready then Act.Action(Act);`. То есть параметры получаются и используются в разных потоках, вот. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Если имеется ввиду механизм событий, то:

```
TMyEvent = procedure(const Param1, Param2: string) of object;
TMyAction = class(TObject)
public
  FParam1: string;
  FParam2: string;
  FParam3: string;
  FAction1: TNotifyEvent; // Можно прикрутить стандартный обработчик procedure(Sender: TObject)
  FAction2: TMyEvent; // Свой формат обработчкчика procedure(const Param1, Param2: string)
end;
```

В коде, для запуска, нужно будет проверить назначен обработчик или нет:

```
if Assigned(FAction2) then
begin
  FAction2("123", "234");
end;
```

Comment: События - интересный вариант, спасибо, но его я на последние попытки отложу, это все же не то, что надо, но как костыль сойдет.

Comment: В событиях реализуется вариант передачи указателя на метод объекта. Если нужно передавать указатель на обычные функции то можно использовать что-то типа:

    type TUserProc = procedure(Param1, Param2: String);

Но такой вариант используется не часто, в Delphi все же удобнее работать с объектами.

Comment: А помоему, это вы (@Sh4dow) костыль собираетесь сделать.
Правда в вышеприведенном коде 2 action не нужно. (FAction1: TNotifyEvent;) лишнее

Comment: FAction1 и FAction2 я поставил чтобы показать вариант использования обычного TNotifyEvent и пользовательского.

Comment: @shurik я собираюсь сделать класс с динамическим методом (объекты одним методом и различаются). Динамический метод - решение, а вызывать событие прямым вызовом (из другого класса, например) - по-моему, костыль)<pre>if (act = 'go') then
  with MyAction1 do begin
   Param1 := var1;
   Param2 := var2;
   Action := goProcedure;
   end;</pre>вот что-то подобное нужно.

Comment: Так может есть смысл сделать предка с абстрактным методом, и отнаследовать от него классы с нужной логикой в Action?

Comment: А я потому и спросил, что интересны все варианты и особенно те, которые подходят для решения задачи)

Comment: shurik "А помоему, это вы (@Sh4dow) костыль собираетесь сделать"
Какакя разница если у человека есть вопрос то почему бы ему не ответить ,
Мужет у него есть идея для которой именно это нужно.
А если нет ответа зачем придираться к человеку.

Comment: Ну, а вызывать как вы эту процедуру будете ?
Вот как будете Вызывать внутри MyAction1 передайте параметры
и выйдет тоже самое что и код выше

Answer (score 1):

Почти угадал

```
  TMyAction = class(TObject)
  Param1: string;
  Param2: string;
  Param3: string;
  Action: procedure (Sender:TObject)
```

Приблизительно так должен выглядеть класс

```
procedure someFunc (Sender:TObject);
begin
end;
procedure someFunc2 (Sender:TObject);
begin
end;

[...]
begin
[...]
MyAction1.Action := someFunc;
MyAction2.Action := someFunc2;
end.
```

Вот приблизительно так выглядит общий принцип.

Comment: Блин, до дельфей добраться не могу сейчас. А Unsatisfied forward declration я не получу таким образом? Имеется в виду, там точно никаких директив а ля **stdcall;** и тп не надо? Еще хотелось бы иметь возможность их переназначать.

Comment: Если у тебя прцедуры someFunc вызываются из Dll то нужно.
А Unsatisfied forward declration выдает в том случае если у класса предка есть свойство с тем же названием но другово типа.
Да и главное объявления Action и someFunc долны совпадать.
у TObject свойства Action нет это 100% )))

Comment: Окей, а до параметров как добираться?